# AWS - Four load balanced t3.micro vs one t3.medium for a NodeJS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, cluster, node.js

I'm trying to decide which of the two setups would be get me more **price/performance** value with the consideration that I will run a NodeJS API in [cluster mode](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html):

All prices are current rates for [Singapore Region](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/pricing/).

1. Four instances of t3.micro **(2 vCPU, 1 GiB RAM)**

   - Instances : 0.0132 x 4 = 0.0528 usd/h
   - Application Load Balancer: 0.0252 usd/h
2. One instance of t3.medium **(2 vCPU, 4 GiB RAM)**

   - Instance : 0.0528 x 1 = 0.0528 usd/h

It would be clear that using t3.micro with an ALB would **cost more** but would give me (1 vCPU = 1 node), a total of **8 node clusters** but each of the two sharing the 1GiB memory.

On the other hand, I would have **2 node clusters** getting a generous 4 GiB memory.

Assuming either setup would receive the same load/process/requests. I'm having a hard time determining which would be more performant, specifically because I found that nodejs performs better in cluster mode (when an instance has more than 1 core). **Which of these would give me more performance for the cost?**

Comment: Be careful auto scaling t2/t3 instances unless you have t2/t3 unlimited turned on - if they run out of CPU credits you'll get weird problems. To answer your question, one instance has less overheads of things like OS runtime / RAM and updates, so might perform a little better. Multiple instances is more resilient of problems, less downtime when patching / reboots are done, running in multiple AZs etc. You could split the difference and use two t3.small.

Answer (score 1):

Totally depends on the workload and if TLS/SSL is needed. Did some tests with a similar questionset. In terms of CPU usage it was quickly clear, that processing a larger amount of small requests, generates quite a lot overhead on the TLS side which can be terminated on the Load Balancer shifting that CPU usage off the instances.

Load Balanced with instances in multiple Availability Zones can as well be considered more resilient.

On the other hand, memory usage is most likely more efficient on a single instance with a single os level caching mechanim. Also the OS overhead is only there once.

If you really want to optimize the setup, most likely the best way is to setup some load test and compare results. A t2.micro can run out of CPU very quick, but it also heavily depends on the application to run. If it is memory hungry you will be better off with more memory on the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Besides running your `node.js` API on-top of `EC2` instance, you could try to use AWS Lambda.

AWS Lambda free of charge for 1M request per month and 0.20 per 1M request thereafter.

- [AWS Lambda pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/)
- [Node.js App](https://dev.to/adnanrahic/how-to-deploy-a-nodejs-application-to-aws-lambda-using-serverless-2nc7) running using AWS Lambda